# How to create rgb colors from a range of HSB values

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create a RGB color pallete from HSB values (one color for each degree) in a Java SWING app.  My problem is that Color.HSBtoRGB() returns the same value for every degree. I do not understand it.  I searched the Internet and tried a number of examples that do not seem to work on my system.  Anyway, here is a simple working example of my problem:

```
import java.awt.Color;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int rgb, red, green, blue;
    for (int i = 0; i < 360; i++) {
        rgb = Color.HSBtoRGB((float)i, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        red = (rgb >> 16) &0xFF;
        green = (rgb >> 8) &0xFF;
        blue = rgb &0xFF;
        System.out.format("%d %x %d %d %d \n", i, rgb, red, green, blue);
       }
    }
}
```

My output looks like this

```
0 ffff0000 255 0 0 
1 ffff0000 255 0 0 
2 ffff0000 255 0 0 
3 ffff0000 255 0 0 
4 ffff0000 255 0 0
```

All 360 colors are RED.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The `hue` parameter should be a value between `0` and `1` or should have a value with such fractions. You are currently only provide discrete integer values (which don't have fractions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#HSBtoRGB(float,%20float,%20float)), hue value is a floating point number between 0 and 1 so you have to divide `i` by `360`.

```
rgb = Color.HSBtoRGB((float)i / 360, 1.0f, 1.0f);
```